# how to get value constraint minimize scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

It seems like a trivial problem, but I cannot find anywhere how to get the value of the constraints using the function minimize from scipy.

I am using the following function:

```
def f(r,d):
   constraint1 = {
        'type': 'ineq',
        'args': (r,),
        'fun': lambda e, r: r- calculate_risk(e) }
   constraint2 = {
        'type': 'ineq',
        'args': (d,),
        'fun': lambda e, d: 1 - np.inner(e,d) }
   optimizeResult = minimize(
                calculate_excess_profit,
                (1/portfolio_parameters.shape[0],)*portfolio_parameters.shape[0],
                method = "SLSQP",
                constraints = (
                        constraint1,
                        constraint2
                        ),
                bounds = get_bounds()
                    )
return optimizeResult
```

and I would like to get the value of constraint 2.

Of course I could add a print statement to the lambda function, but that would print for every iteration. There should be a better way.

Thank you

Comment: Just evaluate the constraint with your solution (! after checking that you obtained a valid solution!). Something like: `constraint2['fun'](optimizeResult.x, constraint2['args'][0]])`.

Comment: Oh, yes of course! Thank you